# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all() when I extract the financials from SEC

Tags: python, data-extraction

Basically, I am trying to automate the extraction of financial statements from the sec portal. Below is my following code and I am getting the following error.

```
url url = 'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1744489/000174448920000151/dis-20200627.htm'
req2 = requests.get(url, headers = header)
df = pd.read_html(req2.text)

for x in df:
  BS = (x[0].str.contains('ASSETS') & x[0].str.contains('Goodwill') & 
          x[0].str.contains('Borrowings') & x[0].str.contains('Retained earnings'))
  if BS.bool():
    balance_sheet = x
balance_sheet
```

NOTE: I have used both the '|' , '&' (and) 'and' , 'or' operators, but I am getting the same error. If anyone have extracted the information, please suggest me an other alternatives also

Comment: please provide some sample data

Comment: You should put all conditions in `()` brackets.

Comment: Your example is not reproducible (`header` is undefined and you haven't provided some sample data for `df`). At first glance, chances are that `BS` is a Series. Try `BS.any()` or `BS.all()` depending on the logic you want to apply.

Comment: also: `for x in df` will just loop through the column names --your code is probably different. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), along with sample input data and desired output data.